# SQL Server job to execute query from the output CSV file of first step

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my first job creation task as a SQL DBA. First step of the job runs a query and sends the output to a .CSV. As a last step, I need the job to execute the query from the .CSV file (output of first step).

I have Googled all possible combinations but no luck.

Comment: How does your output look like? Please show some sample data. Question? Is it necessary to write this into a physical CSV-file? Why?

Comment: If you have written data to a CSV file, how can the query inside be run? The file contains data, not a query.

Comment: Do you perhaps want to import the data in the csv in another database/table?

Comment: my first steps scripts out the current database's logins and roles and everything ......then in the second step im restoring a prod db and finally i have to execute the scripted file to avoid orphaned users........All these things im doing via SQL Server Agent Job

Comment: so how shall we execute the script created in first step?

Comment: I think what's messing up your question is the .CSV - which most folks take to mean comma-separated values. Makes it sound like the output of first step is just data (not scripted stuff)

Answer (score 0):

your question got lost somehow ...

You last two comments make ist a little clearer.

If I understand it correctly you create a SQL script which restores all the logins, roles and users, their rights etc. into a newly created db.

If this created script is executable within a query window you can easily execute it with EXECUTE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188332(v=sql.120).aspx)

Another approach could be SQLCMD (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/10/sql-server-enable-sqlcmd-mode-in-ssms-sql-in-sixty-seconds-048/)

If you need further help, please come back with more details: What does your "CSV" look like? What have you tried so far?